# Error while starting Storage Emulator on windows azure

Tags: c#, windows, azure, emulation, storage

I'm getting the error below while starting the storage emulator. By mistake I deleted the `mdf` and log files in `users/admin` folder. It's holding reference someplace and not allowing me to create the DB again. Please help me.

```
Added reservation for 127.0.0.1:10000/ in user account RaviBorra-PC\Ravi Borra.
Added reservation for 127.0.0.1:10001/ in user account RaviBorra-PC\Ravi Borra.
Added reservation for 127.0.0.1:10002/ in user account RaviBorra-PC\Ravi Borra.

Found SQL Instance (localdb)\v11.0.
Creating database DevelopmentStorageDb201206 on SQL instance '(localdb)\v11.0'.
Cannot create database 'DevelopmentStorageDb201206' : Database 'DevelopmentStorageDb201206' already exists. Choose a different database name..

One or more initialization actions have failed. Resolve these errors before attempting to run the storage emulator again. Please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=248088 for more details.
```

Thank you,
Ravi Krishna B.

Answer (score 30):

Do these steps:

1. Open cmd.exe (Command Prompt)
2. Write this:

   ```
   SqlLocalDb stop "v11.0"
   SqlLocalDb delete "v11.0"
   ```

   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note that "v11.0" is `MyInstance`.

For more details, visit [this link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/).

Comment: If it errors that it's in use use: SqlLocalDb stop "v11.0" 1st before the delete above.

Comment: it worked for me perfectly I just did the SqlLocalDb stop and then the delete command and it worked

Answer (score 29):

This problem may occur if you delete the data file `C:\Users\<Username>\DevelopmentStorageDb201206.mdf` but do not delete the corresponding database on the LocalDB server instance. One possible solution is:

1. Connect to the `(localdb)\v11.0` instance from *SQL Server Management Studio*.
2. Delete the `DevelopmentStorageDb201206` database. There will be the error message that the database deletion ended with an error. Ignore this message and refresh the database list manually.
3. Now you can start the Azure Storage Emulator.

Comment: The file and database could also be called `AzureStorageEmulator*` depending on your SDK version.

Answer (score 13):

This is not a problem related with Azure components rather LocalDB instance is reporting back to Azure request that DB still exist. Check LocalDB instances in your machine using "sqllocaldb i" first and the delete the instance using "sqllocaldb d 'instance_name'". I could not test it in my machine but this may unblock you if localdb instance is blocking you.

In Windows Azure SDK 1.7, Windows Azure Storage Emulator uses LocalDB instance specific configuration at following location:

```
%LocalAppData%\DevelopmentStorage\DevelopmentStorage.201206.config
```

And based on that you will see that v11.0 instance is Windows Azure Storage Emulator specific so verify if that is running and deleting it will let DSInit to create the DB again in LocalDB.

Comment: Hi,  I tried deleting, but i get the error saying "The specified LocalDB instance does not exist."

Comment: I think your best bet is to uninstall local DB and then reinstall it, unless you contact Azure Support to see what else can be done with your local DB. After that run Azure first time and a new DB should be created for Azure Storage.

Comment: As it's been mentioned previously, for certain versions of the emulator the config path would be different. For me it was `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator\AzureStorageEmulator.4.1.config`

Answer (score 10):

If you have Sql Express installed on your local box then (localdb)\v11.0 is most likely not your local Sql instance. It is more likely {MyComputerName}\SQLEXPRESS.

Going to:

```
C:\Users\<yourloginname>\AppData\Local\DevelopmentStorage\DevelopmentStorage.201206.config
```

And changing:

```
 <SQLInstance>(localdb)\v11.0</SQLInstance>
```

To:

```
<SQLInstance>{MyComputerName}\SQLEXPRESS</SQLInstance>
```

solved this error for me.

Comment: Thankyou, thankyou, thankyou... I must have been through every other suggestion and this is the one that finally worked.

Comment: For me it is the best solution! I found WAStorageEmulator settings here: `C:\Users\{user-account}\AppData\Local\WAStorageEmulator` and set this line in preferred version.

Comment: Works for me too. My path was slightly different again though: `C:\Users\<yourloginname>\AppData\Local\AzureStorageEmulator\AzureStorageEmulator.4.1.config`. I assume the path depends on which version you're using.

Comment: I used your solution to simply change the name of the localdb instance in the mentioned configuration file; saved, hit F5 in VS and bingo :) Thanks @Brian

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps..

If you already tried and failed perform:

```
 SQLLocalDB stop v11.0
 SQLLocalDB delete v11.0
 Delete all the files in C:\Users\<accontname>\WAStorageEmulatorDb* (usually one mdf and one ldf)
 Create a new account (I called it Azure, with administrative rights)
 Run again the installation
 Installation completed!
```

For me this works... I had tried to format the PC before use this way. I supposte my problem is related to my username that contains "invalid" characters like Name 'NickName' Surname while the "Azure" account seems to be OK for him.

I figure it out 'cause somewhere in the log I have a property destination path set to "C:\Users\Name$_" that is far away for the path of my user account folder.

After that you can go on CMD.exe and prompt:

```
 control userpasswords2
```

From the control you can delete the Azure login without delete the file folders!

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I simply deleted all the mdf's and ldf's in C:\Users\accountname\ that started with DevelopmentStorage... or WAStorageEmulator.

Re-ran the install and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be caused by the folder not existing for localDB. It looks like Visual Studio / Azure will not automatically create containing folders. I just copied the path from the error code into explorer and created the directory up to the .MDF file.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio go to **Tools -> Options -> Database Tools-> Data connections** and change a localdb instance name from v11.0 to some other name.

Comment: Than you should at least delete the original DB "v11.0" using `SqlLocalDb delete "v11.0"`. Otherwise it would stay there forever. But if you delete it, you don't have to change it in VS. **So the only thing you have to do is to delete the "v11.0" DB.**

Comment: For some reason I cant delete database. SqlLocalDb delete "v11.0" shows no errors but do not delete db actually

Answer (score 0):

I did have SQL Express installed, as Brian Ogden suggested in his answer, but I wanted to try & point Azure Storage Emulator to my SQL Express instance without modifying configuration files.

I did this by running the initialization process for Storage Emulator & passing my server\instance details for SQL Express using the available switches. Below example of the command I executed (from an elevated command prompt):

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe init -server MY-PC-NAME -instance MYSQLINST
```

This created the database successfully (in my SQL Express instance) & got my Storage Emulator working.

I am using a named instance, but I'm thinking this same approach can be used for default instances by omitting the `-instance` switch.